# validates_uniqueness for associations ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a `Measure table` and has the following fields

```
Class Measure < ActiveRecord::Base
  id
  Title
  Question_id
  Answer_id
  Answer_text
end
```

i have `Package table` has column of

```
Class Package < ActiveRecord::Base
  id
  Package_name
end
```

I have `package_measure` table has

```
Class PackageMeasure < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :measure, foreign_key: 'measure_id', primary_key: 'id', class_name: 'Measure'

  id
  package_id
  measure_id
end
```

Now the problem is For the `Package_measure` table.
I can select multiple `measures` for single `package` and I created a `hash` and its working properly. I do not want to add the same `question_id` to the same `package`. How can i achieve this?

I want to do something like the following:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :package_id, :scope => measure.question_id
```

Comment: Just two notes: `validates_uniqueness_of :x` is now `validates :x, :uniqueness => true` and `:scope` works best with a symbol, where here `measure.question_id` is meaningless at the time the scope is defined.

Comment: @tadman Will you please explain how to define the scope correctly?

Comment: if you set your PackageMeasure primary_key=>false and stablish a "through" relationship and use add_clouem unique for package_id and measure_id....wouldn't it solve your problem ?

Comment: @sunny1304 am a newbie to rails so bit confused... would you explain a bit?

Comment: i think if you just go through Rails ActiveRecord Association Doc ,you will solve your problem real soon.

Comment: I could not understand that's why came to here for the solution. Thanks